# Angular bootstrap datepicker handle close / blur

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, blur, handle

I have using angular bootstrap datepicker by:

```
<input type="text" size="7" class="round boxsiz date_picker" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" ng-click="open1()" datepicker-append-to-body="true"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-calendar" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
```

I want when click on close or somewhere outside datepicker form to handle this close/blur event and to execute some function(add/remove class to other element)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yVdEAKD8mwpBUxCBzXLN?p=preview) demo for your problem.Below is the code snippet of how we are handling close event of datepicker popup.

```
 $scope.$watch('popup1.opened', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal != oldVal && !newVal) {
                console.log('popup1 closed');
                $scope.calendarName1 = 'Calender 1';
            }
        }, true);
```

The `is-open` attribute ng-model is changed when you close the popup which is `$scope.popup1.opened`.So that is our target to watch,to perform action on close I've used `$watch()` to watch the scope variable and perform an action required.Inside watcher you can call functions too.

In HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
```

Similar way we can even call our function whenever date is changed by simply calling below code

```
$scope.$watch('dt', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal != oldVal) {
            console.log('date changed');
            $scope.dateChanged = 'Hey you changed date';
        }
    }, true);
```

Comment: @iMarh  this is what you are expecting ?